# In AngularJS, how do I repeat an element twice, but not consecutively?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templating

In my AngularJS template html file, I have an html element such as

```
<div>This is a complicated element that I don't want to type twice</div>
```

and I need that element to appear **twice** in my webpage, but ***not*** **consecutively** (Unlike `ng-repeat` behavior).

The element is small enough where it doesn't make sense to me to make an entire component for it (but maybe I'm wrong).  I hope there is a simple templating feature for this.  A directive might work (but I don't understand them well).

**BONUS**: It would be even better if the two elements could mirror each other.  What I mean is that the element contains a text input, and if the user puts text in one, the other one should update itself accordingly.  This is might qualify as a different question because it might require a different technique.

Comment: if you don't have any logic behind it, then just use an existing directive [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to include it in your HTML

Comment: To your bonus question: My first idea would be to have a two way databinding on each component into a service that holds your state as observable. The service then is injected into each component and updates the value - and gets update by the value

Comment: What you are asking is more complicated than you may realize. To have the two directives "mirrored" you would need either a parent controller that manages communication between the two directives or a service, or simple use of the messaging system with `broadcast` or `emit`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `angularjs` `components`
for example: https://codepen.io/fadihania/pen/bwpdPq

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <my-component>
    <p>Test</p>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .component('myComponent', {
    template: '<div>' +
              '<h1>My Component</h1>' +
              '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
              '</div>',
    transclude: true
  });
```

Then put the `component` as many times as you need and where you need.